# How to define fluent API for curried or partial applicated functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to write one utility that can be used in any of this ways:

```
metadata("Copyright Notice", "John Smith");
metadata.copyright("John Smith");

metadata("Manufacturer", "Canon");
metadata.manufacturer("Canon");
```

How can I approach the problem?

Comment: `metadata.manufacturer = x => metadata("Manufacturer", x)`? There's not much magic behind it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```js
function metadata(a, b) {
    console.log('Metadat function',a,b);
}
metadata.copyright = function (a) {
    console.log('copyright',a);
}
metadata.manufacturer = function (a) {
    console.log('manufacturer',a);
}
metadata("Copyright Notice", "John Smith");
metadata.copyright("John Smith");

metadata("Manufacturer", "Canon");
metadata.manufacturer("Canon");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would this (it sounds like a confusing way to offer an API - if people use it in the wrong way, or unintended way, its best to fail) but it can be done using `Proxy`:

```js
var metadata = function(){

  var data = {};

  return new Proxy(function( k, v ){
 
    return v ? data[ k ] = v : data[ k ];
 
  }, {

    get( target, key ){

      return v => target( key, v );

    }

  });

}();

metadata( 'Copyright Notice', 'John Smith' );
metadata.manufacturer( 'Canon' );

console.log( metadata.manufacturer(), metadata( 'Copyright Notice' ),  )
```

In essence we just set up traps for the `get` property, se when users request `proxy.manufacturer` it will return a function that will already have the key filled in as `manufacturer` - when called it just calls the function it is proxying.

**Update** I made it a private function that returns the proxy. To get the value out, just call the desired function without a value. It will return `undefined` if never set.

Proxies usually are used for debugging. For more info, have a look at this MDN page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy